# Horizontal scroll speed problem in kdiff3

Tags: keyboard, macos

I use [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) Version 0.9.98 (64 bit) on El Capitan.

When comparing files:

- using <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> keys scrolls files by one line (one press or auto-repeat scrolls one line)
- using <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> scrolls files horizontally one pixel at a time

Is there a way to speed up horizontal scroll? For example one character (better yet 8 characters) at a time instead of pixels?

Comment: Same exact issue here. I just installed it and was marveling at its features, then I found this :(

Comment: Though I wish it wasn't necessary, you can always enable Word Wrap...

Answer (score 1):

So for me I have a Magic Mouse, and side scrolling doesn't work. Because of how much I scroll around (for better or for worse) I always display the scroll bars in my windows. In kdiff3, I have a bar on the very bottom of the window that is horizontal, and if I use my mouse to click and drag, then it will scroll left and right for me much quicker than one pixel at a time. I still wish side scrolling worked, but for now, this works well.